# How to check if an element is present in all of the subarrays passed into the function? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function intersection(...bigArr)
{ 
  let results = [];
  let compiledArr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < bigArr.length; i++) {//bigArr.length is the number of subarrays
        compiledArr.push(...bigArr[i]);//takes each subarray, deconstructs it and the elements are pushed into compiledArr. 
  }
  const frequencyObj = {};
  let endBound = bigArr[0].length;
  let k = 1
  for(let i = 0; i < compiledArr.length; i++)
  {
    //if the element exists, increase its frequency by 1. If it doesn't, create it and initialize it to 1. After, check if its frequency value === bigArr.length. If so, push to results
    let currentElement = compiledArr[i];

    if(i === endBound)//the program has reached the next subarray
    {
        endBound += bigArr[k].length;
        k++;
        turnTrue(frequencyObj) //turn the boolean value for each property to true. This is because we are analyzing a different subarray.
    }

    if(!frequencyObj[compiledArr[i]])//if the element DNE in the object, then add it
        frequencyObj[compiledArr[i]] = [1, false];
    
    else if( frequencyObj[currentElement]  &&  frequencyObj[currentElement][1] === true)//if the element already exists, we need to make sure that we only increment its frequency iff we are in a different subarray within compiledArr
    {
        frequencyObj[currentElement][0] += 1;
        frequencyObj[currentElement][1] = false;

        //check if the frequency of that element === bigArr.length, it means it appears in all subarrays. 
        if(frequencyObj[currentElement][0] === bigArr.length)
            results.push(currentElement);
    }

  }
  return results;
    
}

function turnTrue(obj)
{
    for(let key in obj)
        obj[key][1] = true;
}


let result = intersection([1,2,1], [4,1,3,1,4], [3, 1, 2,6]);
console.log(result);
```

The program above has the the purpose of outputting an array with elements that are present in all of the subarrays passed into the intersection function.

This program accounts for duplicates within one subarray. The frequency is only marked when an element appears for the first time in a subarray. For example, given the three test subarrays [1,2,1], [4,1,3,1,4], [3, 1, 2,6], any element can only have a max frequency of the number of subarrays(in this case 3). An element is only marked once per subarray.
This is the only solution I could think of and I know that there exists a more simpler solution. Can anyone rate this code and indicate what could be a better solution?

Comment: stack overflow is not for code review. See [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777) to see if your question would fit on codereview.stackexchange instead (it might not).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for a basic Set intersection, which can be done using the standard JavaScript Set object.  Please see [Set](//https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for more info.

You could however be asking for a count of how many times each element appears, but your question isn't explicit about this (and can only be either 0 if the set is empty, or the `.length` of your data array)

```js
data = [ [1,2,1], [4,1,3,1,4], [3, 1, 2,6] ]

// intersection is taken verbatim from MDN docs linked
function intersection(setA, setB) {
  const _intersection = new Set();
  for (const elem of setB) {
    if (setA.has(elem)) {
      _intersection.add(elem);
    }
  }
  return _intersection;
}

let set = data.reduce( (a, e) => {
  // test includes the possibility that the leading elements are empty
  return (a && a.size)? intersection(a, new Set(e)) : new Set(e)
}, null)

console.log([...set])
```

Comment: I didn't know that that function existed. This problem is from a challenge online and I cannot use any built-in function that would automatically produce the output. Given that condition,  my code above is a solution giving me the intersection of all subarrays. What do you think about my code and is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Yes, but that's a completely different set of requirements.

Comment: @WilliamG might want to point out that "built in functions" include `Array.prototype.push` and `console.log`.